# Has Streamsets / datacollector-oss gone proprietary after SDC version 4.x?

Tags: streamsets

I am unable to find any link to download Streamsets SDC Opensource version. Looks like they no longer will release opensource version of Streamsets/datacollector-oss. The last version of datacollector-oss was Apr 27, 2021 on GitHub and there are no further commits after that. There is no opensource version after 4.x so is it safe to assume that SDC datacollector-oss is dead as open source and will only be proprietary henceforth.

Comment: We started looking into Apache Nifi as replacement for SDC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Streamsets went proprietary. The current product is called DataOps Platform and includes, apart of SDC, a cloud-based Control Hub, as well as engines for running data transformations in Spark and Snowflake.